# Radio input values not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I am trying to populate the radio input values on the page but the code I used below does not work. It does not populate, fetch or show on the database and the front page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
      $('.show_field').hide();
      $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.show_field {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Question here?</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="option" class="trigger" data-rel="yes" id="edit_checked" value="Yes" />Yes
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="option" class="trigger" data-rel="no" id="edit_checked" value="No" />No
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="option" class="trigger" data-rel="unknown" id="edit_checked" value="Unknown" />Unknown
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the code is incomplete. Nowhere in the above provided code it does any population or fetching of data. All your code is doing is showing an element of given class name. You didn't put the whole code. Can't help, sorry.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that your HTML and JavaScript is not correct I will try to show you how to show and hide elements based on the selected value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.show_field').hide();
  $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
 });
});
```

```css
.show_field {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Question here?</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="option" class="trigger" data-rel="yes" id="edit_checked" value="Yes" />Yes
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="option" class="trigger" data-rel="no" id="edit_checked" value="No" />No
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="option" class="trigger" data-rel="unknown" id="edit_checked" value="Unknown" />Unknown
    </label>
</div>

<div class="show_field yes">
yes
</div>
<div class="show_field no">
no
</div>
<div class="show_field unknown">
unknown
</div>
```

To dynamically set the checked value of the radio group you first select the radio group and specify it with the radio input based on the data-rel aatribute.

```
var value = 'yes';

$("input[name=option][data-rel=" + value + "]").prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're having is syntactical in nature. If your code is exactly as you have it above, you're missing your closing `});` on your `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

I've recreated your code in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ojbgtL3c/). It seems to be working as I understand your problem.